# Storing a set of variables with set values in javascript using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

To begin with, I'm COMPLETELY new to js. A week ago the company I work for moved me from a manual labor job to web development because I'm cheap, learn quickly and have some IT/programming experience (but 0 web development experience).

I'm working on a form for ordering a system my company makes. I have a set of part # variables with set values. I need them to equal 1 part number, while storing both the name of the original variable and there original values. If I use an array to do this, will I loose the original variable name when it index's?

I've read all of the w3s pages on arrays and variables. I also read about objects and was wondering if creating this as an object might be a better solution.

This is the code I've got.

```
case '16 x 32':

        var Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty = [var Pn_VFH2014_qty = 1, var Pn_52001_qty = 4, var Pn_55015_qty = 2, var Pn_SDT3011_qty = 4, var Pn_10507_qty = 2, var Pn_PAC1007_qty = 1, var Pn_UT22674_qty = 3, var Pn_55031_qty = 3];
        var Pn_VTP1632PKA_qty = [var Pn_VFH2014_qty = 1, var Pn_52001_qty = 4, var Pn_55015_qty = 2, var Pn_SDT3011_qty = 4, var Pn_10507_qty = 2, var Pn_PAC1007_qty = 1, var Pn_UT22674_qty = 3, var Pn_55031_qty = 3,
             var Pn_55024_qty = 8, var Pn_AC0002_qty = 1, var Pn_22116_qty = 7];

        if(trim($('#Include_Aluminum_Coping option:selected').text()) == 'Yes') {
            Pn_VTP1632PKA_qty;
        } else {
            Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty;
        }

        TS = 193;
        TL = 396;
```

Comment: What you posted isn't even valid JS to start with? It's not very clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want an object rather than an array. Something like:

```
var Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty = { 
    Pn_VFH2014_qty : 1, 
    Pn_52001_qty : 4, 
    Pn_55015_qty : 2,
    // an so on...
};
```

Now you can quickly (ugly variable names apart) find out the number of `Pn_VFH2014_qty` like this:

```
var howMany = Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty.Pn_VF2014_qty;
```

You can loop through all the components with something like this:

```
for (var key in Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty) {
   if (Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log(key + ":" Pn_VTP1632PKN_qty[key]);
   }
}
```

But I suspect you should look for a better way to handle your data because it looks like you are trying to hard code a lot of data into a webpage that ought to be retrieved from, for example, a web service that connects to a database.

Comment: Excellent, thank you sir. The Pn's go back into a database that handles billing and ordering but the point of this specific form is to create a pre packaged system for something that is usually custom made. I was told to do it this way, so I'll do it. Also, I've been doing this for a week and I'd be willing to bet that any real web developer would probably break down and cry at what they've given me to work with as far as "finished code". There's one page that starts by declaring 1000 variables (Litterally, 1 per line for a 1000 lines)